# FFMPEG avformat_open_input returned error

Tags: ffmpeg

Sorry I have to ask this question, but I couldn't find a reference to the return codes of avformat_open_input, and I couldn't find anyone asking/answering about mine.

After this call to the function

```
err = avformat_open_input(&pFormatCtx, is->filename, NULL, NULL);
```

I get err = -13. What does it mean, and if anybody answers, please also share how you know which code corresponds to which error.

UPDATE:
OK, I finally figured out how to turn the code into a message, and the message is "Permission denied". Does anyone have an idea where the problem with this might be?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

1. See libavutil/error.h for the error code definitions, but they mostly match negative `errno` values. You can use `av_strerror` function to get the meaningful message.
2. "Permission denied" most likely means the file you point to in `is->filename` could not be opened due to permissions. Run `strace` on your app if you think this isn't the case.

Comment: Thanks, I found the function for the error codes, and the permission denied was because I was developing on Android, but forgot to give the app permissions for the sdcard.

Comment: When you get an error in native code it sometime helps to try to do the same in Java code (open a file, establish a connection) to get a clearer error message, which would in your case likely be missing READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE or something like that.

Comment: It does help but, all week I had been drowning in the native code of the application, and so naturally when another error popped out of there it never occurred to me to look elsewhere.

Comment: The av_strerror was returning "Invalid data found when processing input", but it turned out I was missing av_register_all and avcodec_register_all

Answer (score 0):

If you run the code on Android, you should give the permissions such as `NETWORK`, `SDCARD`, or You will get the err code -13.